# Distinct manifolds with the same configuration spaces?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory, manifolds, configuration-spaces

For a space $X$, let $C_k X$ denote the space of configurations of $k$ distinct unordered points in $X$.

> What is an example of a pair of smooth manifolds $M$ and $N$ that are not homeomorphic but such that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, the spaces $C_k M$ and $C_k N$ are homotopy equivalent?

(This question is prompted by David Ayala's work on automorphisms of Ran spaces, and more generally the question of the strength of topological field theory invariants.)

Update: Qiaochu and Ricardo answered the question using examples of manifolds with boundary and non-compact manifolds, respectively, so let's now restrict attention to the (no doubt much harder) issue that is most directly relevant for TFT invariants:

> Is there an example where the manifolds are closed?

Comment: $k > 1$ ;-) Another nice question is obtained by modifying the hypothesis and asking that the configuration spaces be homotopic *for all sufficienty large $k$*.

Comment: @alvarez: asking that $M$ and $N$ themselves be homotopy equivalent doesn't trivialize the problem.

Comment: @cdouglas: Out of curiosity, what is David Ayala's work on automorphisms of Ran spaces?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: you're right; it was a slip on my part.

Answer (score 11):

I will present an example involving only (non-compact) manifolds without boundary. As far as I know, the analogous problem for closed manifolds is wide open. Nevertheless, the article [*Configuration spaces are not homotopy invariant*](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401075) by Paolo Salvatore and Riccardo Longoni is very much worth looking at (it was published in Topology, volume 44, number 2, 2005, pages 375-380).$\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}$$\newcommand{\Conf}{\mathrm{Conf}}$$\newcommand{\To}{\longrightarrow}$

**Proposition:** Assume $n \geq 3$. Let $W$ be a contractible topological $n$-manifold without boundary, and $O \subset W$ an open subspace homeomorphic to $\RR^n$. Then the inclusion of $O$ into $W$ induces homotopy equivalences on all ordered and unordered configuration spaces.

A few consequences of this are:

- An embedding $V \to W$ between contractible $n$-manifolds without boundary induces a homotopy equivalence on all ordered and unordered configuration spaces.
- If $V$ and $W$ are contractible $n$-manifolds without boundary, then there are homotopy equivalences $\Conf(V,k) \simeq \Conf(W,k)$ between their ordered configuration spaces, and $C_k V \simeq C_k W$ between their unordered configuration spaces.
- In particular, the configuration spaces, both ordered and unordered, of the [Whitehead manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_manifold) are homotopy equivalent to the corresponding configuration spaces of $\RR^3$.

---

The remainder of this post discusses the proof of the proposition above. Here is a lemma which will be used.

**Lemma:** Let $S$ be any finite subset of $O$. Then the inclusion $O\setminus S \to W\setminus S$ is a weak equivalence.

*Proof*:
Apply the van Kampen theorem to the open cover of $W$ by $O$ and $W\setminus S$. Since $O\setminus S$ is simply connected (since it is equivalent to a wedge sum of $(n-1)$-dimensional spheres), it follows that $\Pi_1(W\setminus S) \simeq \Pi_1(W)$ is trivial.

Now apply the Mayer–Vietoris sequence for homology to the same open cover of $W$ by $O$ and $W\setminus S$. The contractibility of $W$ implies that the inclusion $O\setminus S \to W\setminus S$ is a homology equivalence. Since both spaces are simply connected, this inclusion is also a weak equivalence. ■

Now we prove that the map on ordered configuration spaces $\Conf(O,k) \to \Conf(W,k)$ is a weak equivalence for any $k>0$. Note that we have a map of (horizontal) fibration sequences
$$
\begin{matrix}
O\setminus S & \To & \Conf(O,k) & \To & \Conf(O,k-1) \\
\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow \\
W\setminus S & \To & \Conf(W,k) & \To & \Conf(W,k-1)
\end{matrix}
$$
where $S$ is any subset of $O$ of size $k-1$. The previous lemma states that the map on the fibres is a weak equivalence. Thus, by induction on $k$, we conclude that the map $\Conf(O,k) \to \Conf(W,k)$ is a weak equivalence.

Now the result for unordered configuration spaces follows since we have a commutative diagram of fibration sequences
$$
\begin{matrix}
\Sigma_k & \To & \Conf(O,k) & \To & C_k O \\
\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow \\
\Sigma_k & \To & \Conf(W,k) & \To & C_k W
\end{matrix}
$$
which is an equivalence on the fibres and total spaces. We conclude that the map on the base spaces is also a weak equivalence.

Comment: @cdouglas, it was my pleasure! I only thought of this because of your question, so I should thank you as well. By the way, you can use a similar argument to show, more generally, that any codimension zero embedding between manifolds which is also a weak equivalence induces a weak equivalence between all (ordered and unordered) configuration spaces. One difference is that you need to use excision in homology with local coefficients where above I used the Mayer-Vietoris sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Let $M = \mathbb{R}^2, N = D^2$. In both cases I think the configuration space of $k$ distinct unordered points has the homotopy type of $K(B_k, 1)$. More generally I think we can take $N$ to be a manifold with boundary and $M = N \setminus \partial N$, and there should be some reasonable generalization of this but I can't think of a precise statement. It would be interesting to find an example where $M$ and $N$ are both closed manifolds (or show that one doesn't exist!).

Comment: Yes indeed, sorry: I was thinking of smooth manifolds ... I should get out more.